# SSH call does not see correct $path which exists on a server

Tags: path

On Ubuntu 14.04 I try to establish Drush through Composer.

I added  `PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` to either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` on a server.

Drush is invoked properly on the server.

But it does not properly for remotely:

`ssh myalias 'drush'
bash: drush: command not found`

I checked `echo $PATH` for both the webserver and remotely and I saw:

- on the webserver: `/home/<MY_USER>/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`
- on the remote call: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

Why there is a difference (there is not `/home/<MY_USER>/.composer/vendor/bin`)?
How to add the correct path for remotely callbacks?

Comment: Which machine is it invoked properly on? ("the server"? is that the same "the webserver"?) Which machine you open the SSH connection from? And to which machine? Call them by name, show the commands you run. And to which machines' `.bashrc` you added the `PATH` assignment? What do you mean with a "callback"?

Comment: did you source the .bashrc or .bash_profile that you changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions here:

- `drush` is installed within `~/.composer/vendor/bin`
- `myalias` is the name of the remote host on which you have `drush`
- the webserver you mention is actually the same as `myalias` in your example command

When you log in interactively with `bash` as your shell, the `bash` startup script `.bash_profile` is executed. If you set your `PATH` here all is well and good, and you can find `drush` directly.

When you run something non-interactively such as `ssh remotehost id`, there is no login shell so `.bash_profile` is not run. However, since your shell is `bash` the session script `.bashrc` is executed. I suspect you don't set your `PATH` there, so `drush` cannot be found.

There are several options open to you. Here are four suggestions

1. Make `.bashrc` call `.bash_profile` if it's not previously been called by this shell (my preference)
2. Add a duplicate `PATH=...` line in `.bashrc` (easy)
3. Move the environment settings out of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` into a common file that's sourced by `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` (more elegant)
4. Install `drush` in a system location (such as `/usr/local/bin` or somewhere under `/opt`) and ensure that this directory is included in the system-wide `PATH` settings (harder)

Comment: Thank you, roaima.
It works only if I add ```PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"```
at the begin of ```.bashrc```.

Comment: You understood all correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" ssh myalias 'drush'
```

will provide for the modified `PATH` to `ssh` and any utilities that it invokes.

Answer (score 0):

One other option (seen on the documentation here: https://www.drush.org/latest/site-aliases/)

Is to add the path to the drush script or drush launcher.

In your drush site alias file (often self.site.yml) add the following:

```
paths:
    drush-script: '/path/to/drush'
```

This will run the command using the drush script that doesn't necessarily have to be on the PATH variable.